# Best way to manage file transfert of heavy folders

Tags: php, ftp, file-transfer

The situation is a bit complicated here.
We are receiving large folders with lots of files on a distant fileserver (accessible with FTP, let's say `FTP1`).

Thoses folders can have a **complex** arboresence and weigh between **50Mo** and **4Go**.

With PHP, the goal is to remove unwanted files (.exe, .pdf ...).
Take all files and put them on the root folder and then order them by creating a new defined arborescence.

And after this process, the webserver should send everything to another distant FTP server (`FTP2`).

Then folders/files can be removed from `FTP1`

With laravel and `Storage` everything is easy to make but my main concern is about the speed.

Is it better to

- Copy file on webserver, launch process, copy to distant and then clean
- Process directly on `FTP1` and then copy to `FTP2`
- Copy to `FTP2` and then process directly on `FTP2`

I dont have that much experience in IT infrastructure/architecture but both FTP are only accessible through internet and will never be in the same network as the webserver.

The connection between FTP's servers and webserver should be on high availability but we all knows what it means ...

I dont expect an answer but more like a guideline or the the usual way of dealing with this case.

Comment: Hmmm. All I can say is that you will slow the process if you have to use 2 FTP servers and therefore have to move things twice

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand you. By 50Mo do you mean 50mb? But anyway, since you are just looking for a rough guide and from what i see,

You should

1. Reduce the need for FTP because FTP is extremely slow. So if you can have 1 FTP transfer over 2, it is definitely better.
2. Check your ftp servers hardware specification. You obviously want the faster one to do the processing.

Comment: By 50Mo I mean 50MB or 400mb. And the network will alway be the bottleneck. We have 10Go network cards and a network in compliance with this rate but anyway the FAI will always limit this rate.

Comment: Mo (Mega Octet) is french acronym for Mb. 1 octet = 1 byte = 8 bits

Comment: And as say Raccoon, FTP is slow. I would fetch folder contents, generate a list of action to do (create folder, copy / delete file, ...)  and apply it. Avoid copy of files on webserver with function `stream_copy_to_stream`